# 'rs'-like command line util for working with text arrays in more than 2 dimensions?

Tags: linux, command-line, plain-text

Utils like [`rs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) and [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) work as though the lines and field separators of a given file were members of a *2-dimensional* array.  Text utils that work with columns and fields might also be loosely grouped in this *2d* category, (`cut`, `head`, `tail`, `paste`, `join`, etc.).

If lists of *filenames* are considered as a third dimension, we have a crude *3d*.  Given a list of *filenames*, if we wish to print the 3rd *file*'s 3rd *row*'s 3rd *column*, we can pipe various utils together and get a result.  But can any util, (that's *not* a language), do that in one command?

```
# Hypothetical program syntax.
# output row 3, col 3, of file3 (i.e. the third file in list)
foobar3dcut -f 3,3,3 file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

Or:

```
# Output 2d table of column 3s (one column from each file)
foobar3dcut -f .,3,. file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

Higher dimensions than *3d* (e.g. directories) would be good also...

*Not very relevant*:  General or special purpose programming languages.  Spreadsheets.  Recommendations for emulating *3d* output with a series of pipes and filters, or with `find`, `set`, `xargs`, *et al*.  Reflections on the *type*less *1d* nature of file streaming.